# How should I access an element's angularjs $ngModelController in a jasmine unit test?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-directive

I'm currently using `directiveElement.data("$ngModelController")` to get access to the element's `$ngModelController`, as in the following example.

```
describe("directiveElement", function () {
  it("should do something with ngModelController", inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var directiveElement = $compile("<input ng-model="myNgModel" customDirective type="text"></input>")($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    var ngModelCtrl = directiveElement.data("$ngModelController");
    ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = "12345";
    // do rest of test
  }));
});
```

However, I want to know if there is a better to access the `$ngModelController`, or if accessing the `$ngModelController` is a bad idea?

Comment: You could also do `directiveElement.controller('ngModel')`. I also certainly think there are legitimate testing reasons why you would want a handle on this, though the more common way is to get a handle on it through the `form` (eg. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/formSpec.js). Not sure why you're setting $modelValue this way though. Don't you probably just want to set `myNgModel`?

Comment: @jonc Your comment is the answer I was looking for, can you please post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: were you able to mock ngModelCtrl.$modelValue ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could also do `directiveElement.controller('ngModel')`.

I certainly think there are legitimate testing reasons why you would want a handle on this, though the more common way is to get a handle on it through the form (eg. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/formSpec.js)

Comment: had 'ngModelController' for an hour and couldn't figure this one out.  Thanks!